# Explicitly understanding the implicit function theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, inverse, implicit-function-theorem, pseudoinverse, inverse-function

Suppose I have a curve $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the *implicit function theorem* guarantees the existence of a smooth local inverse of this function $f$.

**Question:**
My question is is there a way to explicitly find the form of these local inverses?

**Particular Case:**
Particularly I'm looking for the local inverses of the curve drawn-out b the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x):=a_1xe^{-b_1x}+a_2x^2e^{-b_2x}+...+a_nx^ne^{-b_nx}
\end{equation}
where $a_1,..,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_1,..,b_n \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "a curve $f$ in ${\mathbb R}^2\>$", a "local inverse of this function $f\>$", and what do these have to do with the displayed expression?

Comment: I'm looking for open intervals $(c_i,d_i)$ and functions $f_i:(c_i,d_i) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ f_i\circ f =f$ on $(c_i,d_i)$, by a curve i mean the function $f(x)$.

Comment: Usually the answer is no: actually calculating the local inverses instead requires numerics. Only in very nice cases (e.g. the circle) can they be explicitly calculated.

Comment: Thought, so I tried the above with $n=3$ and the resulting function was pretty complex (pun intended)

Comment: I'm used to thinking of the implicit function when the dimension of the domain is bigger than that of the codomain (which agrees with Wikipedia's version of it).  Could you elaborate on how you are using it here?